# why $(':not(:has(*))').find("p"); won't give an output

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I wanted to get the parent node of a text, and I know that it's not easily possible and should be done with manual traversing. but I want to know why  the following is not working.

```
$(':not(:has(*))').find(':contains("mytext")');
```

I made it easier with just looking for p  tag in the result.
I know `$(':not(:has(*))');` would return some P tags
`.find("p");` should select those P tags

I know it's not working but I want to know why?

Comment: Go through it logically... "Find all that, does not contain, contains everything, in which find p." That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: basically my understanding was "has" just checks for tags inside a tag and contains checks for texts inside a tag.
so getAllTagsThatHasNoTagsInThemAndMayContainAPlainText().GetTheOnesThatHave("myText");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to find descendant elements of elements with no descendants. That's not going to work.

If you're looking for `p` elements with no descendants, you probably meant to use `.filter()`, not `.find()`:

```
$(':not(:has(*))').filter('p')
```

Or you can just attach the `p` selector to the `:not()` — there really is no reason to run a separate selector here (unless your selector string is coming from a variable or something):

```
$('p:not(:has(*))')
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying. i did not know that find looks for the items inside the tag